# DataTables warning: Json Response not working

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, datatables

I am trying to filter my table with a IDcompany dropdown and it works for all my options except one where the following message appears:

> DataTables warning: table id=empTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

I checked the json response from the debugger network tab but there was nothing listed there. I assumed the problem was with my query, however I echoed it and it is correctly constructed and works if I write it in Phpmyadmin.

I have the exact same code in a container and it works perfectly fine but in my production server it has the above issues. When I add a specific filter for status though it works correctly but only for that specific filter.

#### How I create my query:

(it works with everything else)

```
$empQuery = "select t.ID, c.name as IDcompany, v.name as IDvessel, w.name as IDwarehouse,
        t.orderno, s.name as IDstatus, su.name as IDsupplier, t.warehouseno, t.orderdate,
        t.datereceived, t.packages, t.weight, t.dimensions, r.name as shippingremarks,
        dan.name as IDdangerous, t.transportorderno, t.pacorefno, t.datedeliveredtovessel,
        t.destination, t.methodofdelivery, t.edt, t.description, t.description_color,
        t.orderdue, t.document, grp.groups
    from transactions t
    left join vessels v on t.IDvessel=v.ID
    left join companies c on t.IDcompany=c.ID
    left join statuses s on t.IDstatus=s.ID
    left join suppliers su on t.IDsupplier=su.ID
    left join warehouses w on t.IDwarehouse=w.ID
    left join remarks r on t.shippingremarks=r.ID
    left join yesno dan on t.IDdangerous=dan.ID
    left join admin_groups grp on t.groups=grp.ID
    WHERE t.deleted = 'No' "
    .$admQuery
    .$searchQuery
    ." order by ".$columnName." ".$columnSortOrder
    ." limit ".$row.",".$rowperpage;
```

#### How I create my json request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var dataTable = $('#empTable').DataTable({

          'processing': true,
          'serverSide': true,
          'serverMethod': 'post',
          //-- to remove the extra filter --
          'bFilter': false,
           //-- to move the sorting icon in the first row of the thead in the table --
          'bSortCellsTop': true,
          //-- to remove the sorting in action column --
          'columnDefs': [{
            'orderable': false,
            'targets': [0,1,25]
            }],

          // "scrollX": false,

          //'bAutoWidth': false,
          // 'fixedColumns': true,
          'oLanguage': {
            'oPaginate': {
              'sNext': 'Next'
            }
          },
          "aaSorting": [[2,'asc']],
          'async': false,
          "pageLength": 50,

          'ajax': {
              'url':'ajaxfile.php',
              // 'async':true,
              'data': function(data){
                  // Read values
                  var company = $('#searchByCustomer').val();
                  var vessel = $('#searchByVessel').val();
                  var warehouse = $('#searchByWarehouse').val();
                  var orderno = $('#searchByOrderNo').val();
                  var status = $('#searchByStatus').val();
                  var supplier = $('#searchBySupplier').val();
                  var warehouseno = $('#searchByStockNo').val();
                  var orderdate = $('#searchByOrderDate').val();
                  var datereceived = $('#searchByDateReceived').val();
                  var packages = $('#searchByCLL').val();
                  var weight = $('#searchByWeight').val();
                  var dimensions = $('#searchByPacoEyes').val();
                  var shippingremarks = $('#searchByRemark').val();
                  var IDdangerous = $('#searchByDGR').val();
                  var transportorderno = $('#searchByTransportNo').val();
                  var pacorefno = $('#searchByPacoRef').val();
                  var datedeliveredtovessel = $('#searchByDateDelivered').val();
                  var destination = $('#searchByDeliveredAt').val();
                  var methodofdelivery = $('#searchByMethodOfDelivery').val();
                  var edt = $('#searchByEstimatedDelivery').val();
                  var description = $('#searchByDescription').val();
                  var description_color = $('#searchByColor').val();
                  var orderdue = $('#searchByValue').val();
                  var groups = $('#searchByGroup').val();

                  // Append to data
                  data.searchByCustomer = company;
                  data.searchByVessel = vessel;
                  data.searchByWarehouse = warehouse;
                  data.searchByOrderNo = orderno;
                  data.searchByStatus = status;
                  data.searchBySupplier = supplier;
                  data.searchByStockNo = warehouseno;
                  data.searchByOrderDate = orderdate;
                  data.searchByDateReceived = datereceived;
                  data.searchByCLL = packages;
                  data.searchByWeight = weight;
                  data.searchByPacoEyes = dimensions;
                  data.searchByRemark = shippingremarks;
                  data.searchByDGR = IDdangerous;
                  data.searchByTransportNo = transportorderno;
                  data.searchByPacoRef = pacorefno;
                  data.searchByDateDelivered = datedeliveredtovessel;
                  data.searchByDeliveredAt = destination;
                  data.searchByMethodOfDelivery = methodofdelivery;
                  data.searchByEstimatedDelivery = edt;
                  data.searchByDescription = description;
                  data.searchByColor = description_color;
                  data.searchByValue = orderdue;
                  data.searchByGroup = groups;
              }
          },
          'columns': [
              { data: 'action' },
              { data: 'check'},
              { data: 'IDcompany' },
              { data: 'IDvessel' },
              { data: 'IDwarehouse' },
              { data: 'orderno' },
              { data: 'IDstatus' },
              { data: 'IDsupplier' },
              { data: 'warehouseno' },
              { data: 'orderdate' },
              { data: 'datereceived' },
              { data: 'packages' },
              { data: 'weight' },
              { data: 'dimensions' },
              { data: 'shippingremarks'},
              { data: 'IDdangerous' },
              { data: 'transportorderno' },
              { data: 'pacorefno' },
              { data: 'datedeliveredtovessel' },
              { data: 'destination' },
              { data: 'methodofdelivery' },
              { data: 'edt' },
              { data: 'description' },
              { data: 'description_color' },
              { data: 'orderdue' },
              { data: 'document' },
              { data: 'groups' },

          ]
      });


      $('#searchByCustomer').change(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByVessel').change(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByWarehouse').change(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByOrderNo').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByStatus').change(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchBySupplier').change(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByStockNo').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByOrderDate').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByDateReceived').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByCLL').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByWeight').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByPacoEyes').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByRemark').change(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByDGR').change(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByTransportNo').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByPacoRef').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByDateDelivered').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByDeliveredAt').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByMethodOfDelivery').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByEstimatedDelivery').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByDescription').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByColor').change(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $('#searchByValue').keyup(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });

      $('#searchByGroup').change(function(){
          dataTable.draw();
      });
      $("#actionReset").bind("click", function() {
          $("input[type=text]").val("");
          $("input[type=checkbox]").val("");
          $("#searchByGroup").val("");
          $("#searchByCustomer").val("");
          $("#searchByVessel").val("");
          $("#searchByWarehouse").val("");
          $("#searchByStatus").val("");
          $("#searchBySupplier").val("");
          $("#searchByRemark").val("");
          $("#searchByDGR").val("");
          $("#searchByColor").val("");

          dataTable.draw();
      });
  });
```

#### $admQuery

```
if($admGroup == 'admin'){
   $admQuery="";
}else if ($admGroup == 'hamburg') {
   $admQuery=" and (grp.groups = '".$admGroup."' 
   or grp.groups = 'common') ";
}
```

#### $searchQuery

```
if($searchByCustomer != ''){
  $searchQuery .= " and (t.IDcompany= '".$searchByCustomer."' ) ";
}
if($searchByVessel != ''){
  $searchQuery .= " and (t.IDvessel='".$searchByVessel."' ) ";
}
if($searchByWarehouse != ''){
  $searchQuery .= " and (t.IDwarehouse='".$searchByWarehouse."' ) ";
}
if($searchByOrderNo != ''){
  $searchQuery .= " and (t.orderno like '%".$searchByOrderNo."%' ) ";
}
...
```

#### Here is a sample of a rendered mysql query:

```
select t.ID, c.name as IDcompany, v.name as IDvessel, w.name as IDwarehouse, t.orderno,
       s.name as IDstatus, su.name as IDsupplier, t.warehouseno, t.orderdate,
       t.datereceived, t.packages, t.weight, t.dimensions, r.name as shippingremarks,
       dan.name as IDdangerous, t.transportorderno, t.pacorefno, t.datedeliveredtovessel,
       t.destination, t.methodofdelivery, t.edt, t.description, t.description_color,
       t.orderdue, t.document, grp.groups
from transactions t
left join vessels v on t.IDvessel=v.ID
left join companies c on t.IDcompany=c.ID 
left join statuses s on t.IDstatus=s.ID 
left join suppliers su on t.IDsupplier=su.ID 
left join warehouses w on t.IDwarehouse=w.ID 
left join remarks r on t.shippingremarks=r.ID 
left join yesno dan on t.IDdangerous=dan.ID
left join admin_groups grp on t.groups=grp.ID
WHERE t.deleted = 'No'
  and (grp.groups = 'hamburg' or grp.groups = 'common')
  and (t.IDcompany= '84' )
  and (t.IDstatus='3' )
order by IDcompany asc 
limit 0,50
```

which is what I get but the Ajax response returns as an error message.

Comment: What is the error message returned?

Comment: The error is: DataTables warning: table id=empTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: Show more code.. how is this json generated?

Comment: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7

Comment: I need to see how `$admQuery` and `$searchQuery` are defined.  You probably have a rogue `and` being written to your query when there are no "filters".  Integer values don't need to be quoted in mysql.   ...erm, you ARE using a prepared statement, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It was not a server side or ajax problem but a database one. Some records had special characters like '–'(German dash) which could not be read by the query correctly and caused an error.

I replaced those records with the normal dash '-' and it worked correctly.